# What is the book containing this puzzle with an unexpected answer?

Tags: books

(To best of my recollection) In the book a diagram was given with the side note something like X vs Y, 1920 or 1930 Morocco or some other place with the question "what did black do?"

After some careful examination it seemed like there is a win for black etc., but when looking up the answer at the end of the book:

> A: If you said (insert combination here) black wins, you are wrong, as in actual game (black missed the winning combination) black resigned!

Anyone can suggest the book that contains this puzzle and answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, [here's a link that contains the game](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/resigntxt.htm#01), probably.  I'd guess it's example #1.  This may give you more information for your research.

Comment: +1 @Tony Ennis: Very impressive that you were able to find what appears to be the correct historical game.

Comment: @blunders Sometimes my Google-fu is strong today. :-)

Comment: Holy cow! I think number 1 is the game! now I got to find the book, it was one of those paperback books. very Impressive!

Comment: Paperback books with old games are frequently from a publisher called Dover.

Comment: @Tony : Yes, now I recal it was a dover book.

Comment: @Arjang: [Dover Chess Books](http://store.doverpublications.com/by-subject-chess.html) - Do any of them appear to be the book you're looking for? If so, which one is it?